# отсортировать массив по возрастанию python

Tags: python

Есть произвольный массив чисел, необходимо отсортировать его в порядке возрастания.
Пробовал воспользоваться методом sort, но не очень продуктивно.

Comment: Это какой-же по размеру "массив чисел" вы использовали, что ощутили "непродуктивность"  метода sort? И чем замеряли "продуктивность"?

Comment: Небольшой массив чисел, проблема была, как я понял с аргументами метода sort.
Продуктивность измерял своими, крайне низкими навыками.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Python весь стандартный функционал идёт в ногу с алгоритмами, так что должен работать быстро. Если этого мало - попробуйте `numpy`.

```
import numpy
massive = [2,3,1,4,7,5,6,1]
ar = numpy.array(massive)
ar.sort()
print(ar)
```

Comment: "ar.sort()"
В данном случае метод сорт вызывается без аргумента, и сортировка выполняется по умолчанию. А какие аргументы нужно ввести, чтобы произошла всё та же сортировка, но с наличием аргументов ?
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну например: kind : {‘quicksort’, ‘mergesort’, ‘heapsort’, ‘stable’} -  выбор метода сортировки. axis : int  -  номер оси, по которой производится сортировка. order:list  - порядок столбцов, в соответствии с которым будет проводиться сортировка.

Comment: Вот тут гляньте про аргументы сортировки: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_sort_search_counting_functions.htm . Аргумент "kind" влияет на способ сортировки, можете поэкспериментировать с ним и замерить скорость при kind='quicksort', 'mergesort', 'heapsort'.